# Is there a better way to permanently stop the spam questions?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, spam

I *just* saw the post as

[`Coin~~Ba$e!!&upp0rt Number ™+⥙【↶ퟷퟖ+1.555⍨555⍨555↶】 ☎️ ๑۩۞۩๑ $$$$$$UMG$$$$$`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70125918/coinbaeupp0rt-number-%E2%A5%99-%ED%9F%B7%ED%9F%961-8044548895-%EF%B8%8F-%E0%B9%91%E0%B9%91-umg)

Is there a permanent solution to stop these spam posts? Yes, I flagged the question as spam and downvoted, but the problem is I've seen 2-3 spam posts across the network these past few days. Why does Stack Overflow allow these messages in the very first place? Stack Overflow should validate it first and then allow to post.

Comment: See [Wallet spam ads getting out of control](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410498/4642212) and [Stopping the s.uPPortNumber ☎️ adver,tising c@mpai\_gn $SPAM$](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413187/4642212). This doesn’t really add anything new. We’re already using several tools to stop as much spam as possible.

Comment: Screen every post? It would prevent Google indexing the spam and keep the sites tidier as seen by low-rep users.

Comment: They reached a rate of about 1-2 every minute now. It's getting kind of insane...

Comment: Dupes?:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170740/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173136/282094

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're actually seeing only [part of them](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/posts):

[image]

The good news is that after an [uncharacteristically long Internet outage](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59694989), SmokeDetector is now [automatically casting spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically) again, so all that type of spam is short-lived now (on the order of a few seconds).

Stack Overflow already employs some anti-spam measures (details are kept secret for obvious reasons), but it's never possible to completely block spam. We simply don't have enough volunteers to approve *all* posts before they become visible on the site.

Comment: [It's time that SE allows you to auto cast spam flags from mod accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291311/320339) :)