# Why has my flag weight stopped at 300?

Tags: support, flags, flag-weight, flag-history

I know 300 is not the cap, so this is not a duplicate question. My flag weight stopped at exactly 300 a few days ago, at the same time I gained the privilege to `Cast close and reopen votes`, so I'm wondering if that's related, or if this is possibly a bug just affecting my account?

Here is my profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/772035/paulpro

When I click on my flagging summary It shows my last flag as being on July 24th. However I've been on everyday since then to get my 200 rep, and I've flagged an average of about 5-10 posts per day too, but none of those flags are showing up in my flagging summary. Most, if not all, the flags I've made have been valid and the posts have been closed. My username has been listed under the post saying it was closed / moved by me and 4 others, so my flags are working. They're just not showing up flagging summary, or affecting my flag weight.

Anybody else ever had this before, or know the cause? Is it a bug?

Comment: "I've been on everyday since then to get my 200 rep." You make it sound so easy... :-/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're just flagging to close, your flags are automatically converted to close votes now that you have [the privilege to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: So do I no longer get flag-weight when I flag posts, unless I flag them specifically for moderator attention rather than a close vote?

Comment: @Paul, yes. You'll still get flag weight for all non-close-vote flags. But note that if you _do_ insist on flagging for mod attention for posts that just need to be closed, instead of just using the close vote privilege you've earned, the mods might start marking your flags invalid for wasting their time.

Comment: Right. Anything under the "it doesn't belong here" corresponds to a specific close vote reason, so now that you're at a reputation level that makes you trusted enough to decide whether or not a post should be closed, the system more actively involves you in the closing process by converting those flags.

Comment: So it's the close vote flags that don't give flag weight, like `Off topic` and such? But those all gave flag weight before I gained the privilege. I don't use any other form of flagging, because usually one of the categories is spot on.

Comment: Indeed, this is by design. What tags are you trawling to find all these close-worthy posts, anyways?

Comment: Okay thanks. Got it :) That makes the `Deputy` badge seem a lot further a way than it did before, haha. Oh well, I don't mind. I'm just glad to have it cleared up. Thanks :)

Comment: @Popular I've just been online a lot, lol. I've just been watching the newest questions feed for questions I might be able to answer and every so often there's one that needs to be moved to serverfault, and there's usually a few valid `Not a Real Question`'s that come up in that span of a few hours.

Comment: @Paul There are plenty of "Not a real answer" candidates (can be found under the Review button next to the badge numbers at the top of the screen) that can be flagged even if you're above 3k.

Comment: @Paul - As jonsca says, look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83075/easy-ways-to-find-answers-that-should-be-comments-for-flagging-purposes and here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99699/who-wants-to-go-spam-hunting for ways of finding content that doesn't belong.  Also, check out the /review page, particularly the late answers, for spam and non-answers.  You can easily max out your flag weight if you sensibly flag things from there.

Comment: @Brad Hey thanks a lot! That was quick :) I just made my first `Not an Answer` flag for an "answer" which just said: "fighting with same problem :-(

pls help"

By using the tip from that page about "same problem"