# Do you stop getting helpful flags once you can vote to close?

Tags: discussion, voting, flags, vote-to-close, moderation

I noticed that once I hit 3,000 rep and could vote to close I seemed to stop getting helpful flags. The behavior is different too. Before I would flag a post for being non-constructive or whatever, then eventually I would get a +1 for being helpful. Now, what happens is when I try to flag a post I get a "Vote to Close" button instead, and after clicking it, a "Your vote to close has been recorded." message. More significantly, my "moderator flags" count does *NOT* increase.

So, what is the story here? People who can vote to close no longer get credit for helpful flags?

Comment: You can flag other stuff than for closing.

Comment: Spam flags, not-an-answer flags, busting sockpuppets, etc.

Comment: You should be voting to close content to better the site; not to make a helpful flag count go up.

Comment: @Servy It's all about badges :-)  I don't do this out of charity.

Comment: I think it is pretty comical this question has a -3 score. It's a valid question and certain different than the "I don't flag" question. The people on meta seem to assume you know everything about and heap scorn on you, if you don't. Sheesh, you didn't KNOW that already, I'm downvoting your question ignoramus.

Comment: @TylerDurden In fact, I downvoted because you repeatedly stated your flags are for badge hunting only. It had nothing to do with how much you know about the site.

Comment: Oh, I see, this is "punishment" for not being politically correct. My question is completely good and valid, but you are downvoting me because you don't like my "attitude". Well, I could care less about my meta reputation, and as for people who go around patroling other people's psychology and deciding who "thinks correctly", they are the definition of evil.

Comment: Yeah, that just about sums it up.

Comment: @TylerDurden, downvotes work differently here. People downvote here when they disagree with your viewpoint too.

Comment: @TylerDurden I will not have my name smeared ("definition of evil") because I was as kind enough to explain you the reason of my downvoting. Also, please note how you just made yourself liable to hypocrisy by criticizing my psychology.

Comment: I vote strictly on the merits of the question. I don't judge people, and I certainly don't falsify question scores or grades because I don't like somebody. You guys are like small minded public high school teachers who give students bad grades because they don't like the student's attitude.

Comment: "Well, I could care less about my meta reputation" You should, then, because meta reputation isn't supposed to matter.

Comment: Act like a _moderator_. You've received this privilege to keep this place tidy.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you can get [Reviewer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer) silver badge and [Steward](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward) gold badge as you do reviews. You can end up adding 6 badges of each, they will look good ;)

Comment: -1 for acting like a spoiled child and ruining an otherwise interesting question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you still get helpful flags.

But not for closing.

When you hit 3k, you can no longer use the 'it doesn't belong here' flag stuff (which sends the flag in to the CV review queue.)

**But** you still can get helpful flags from:

- Not An Answer flags
- Offensive flags
- Spam flags
- VLQ flags
- etc

Anything that isn't a 'it doesn't belong here' flag.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that the other stuff besides "It doesn't belong here" is much rarer, so I can get very few flags this way. This is significant because there is a badge for having 500 helpful flags, but getting this badge will be very, very difficult just flagging spam. I suppose I could start flagging all the posts as "low quality" instead of doesn't belong here, but then I am not really using the best flag anymore.

Comment: @TylerDurden: Why not stop worrying about badges and instead start caring about the site quality? The badge will be a nice surprise some time in the future.

Comment: @Tyler Here's a hint: search + `is:answer` :)

Comment: I am not really the "community service" type. My time is way more valuable than a nebulous, incremental value to "improving the site". I do this for badges.

Comment: @Tyler That's how you get badges. You can turn up some great answers to flag with this: `body:"what have you" is:answer`

Comment: @Undo That is a good tip. Switching to answer patrol seems to be a good idea, thanks Undo.

Comment: Are you aware that badges have absolutely no value whatsoever, while a smoothly running site does?

Comment: @Wooble And we use badges to keep the site smoothly running. If someone wants to keep the site running smoothly, great! If someone wants to go after Deputy, they are keeping the site running smoothly. Win-win.

Comment: @Wooble: Who cares?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: the OP, apparently?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, if you're flagging for a question to be closed and you have the "vote to close" privilege, your flag is automatically converted to a vote.  You don't gain helpful flags for that particular flag type once you reach 3000 reputation.

Answer (score 3):

You can still get helpful flags, one way to do it would be to flag answers.

When you flag an answer, you get several options to select from:

[image].

These answers get placed in a review queue that gets reviewed by moderators and those on the site with 10k+ rep.

There are [many ways that you can find](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172075/164200) content that might need to be flagged including:

- [Data StackExchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) to write or browse queries to find low quality content

Comment: You can still flag questions, too.

Comment: @Undo Yup, that's true.

Answer (score 3):

Allow me to throw my towel here.

I am not a developer/programmer, yet I spend at least 5 hours everyday on stackoverflow. During those hours, I answer questions, give hints, up-vote, down-vote (*rarely*), and most importantly, I review close votes (*which is tremendously increasing*), edits etc...

I have been given privileges to such things, which is - in my humble opinion - a smart move from SE network. They keep you attached to this network, increase your passion towards it.

The idea of [self-moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) is definitely brilliant and appreciated. Each review you do or action you take, makes you feel better. On the other hand, you help keeping this network the center of attention of all developers/programmers and those who are looking for help desperately.

Back to badges, as I mentioned in my [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185638/do-you-stop-getting-helpful-flags-once-you-can-vote-to-close#comment568965_185638) you still can earn badges from reviewing different types of questions and answers.

Comment: You have to stop deluding yourself and face the facts: given your answers on Stack Overflow, you *definitely qualify* as a developer/programmer :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thanks a lot, I appreciate your comment :) but I was unable to answer your last _killing_ questions ;)