# Is spam in the "about me" field a reason to worry?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, spam

There are many inactive user profiles on SO that were clearly registered by spammers. The spam posts (if there were any) are already removed but the profiles remain. Some of them put their spam text into the "about me" field, see for example <strike>[deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498532/internetmarketingnottingham)</strike> and <strike>[deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/723222/match-com-free-trial)</strike>. If you google this text, it has been spammed all over the web. I guess that the purpose is manipulating search engines - when searching for particular keywords a website with a link to the spammer's site will likely come up as a result.

Is that something that we need to worry about? I can see why the answer would be "no": unlike spam in questions, this isn't a problem for SO - nobody sees these profiles. So this isn't really worth investing effort into. Then again, I hate spam and don't like making spammer's life easy.

If the answer to the previous question is "yes", what can be done about it? Obviously, anything requiring much effort from the community or the devs isn't going to work. One solution I can think of: stop displaying "about me" text for profiles that have neither answers nor questions and that have been inactive for at least a month. Maybe stop displaying the webpage link as well.

**Edit**: I found many dozens of user profiles (now all deleted) when searching the user database by the keywords "sms", "market", "website", "free", "cheap", "gift", "flower" and "florist". If you then sort by all time reputation score and concentrate on accounts with reputation 1 to 11 it isn't hard to find lots of spammer accounts. (Some of them have the necessary keywords in their user name, they don't use the "about me" text then.) Still, combing through the user database like this requires far too much effort and I definitely don't think that it is a viable solution.

As staticbeast notes in the comments, the Data Explorer is great for [finding these profiles](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1835/search-for-spam-in-profile-info).

Comment: This for me, whilst not being a major concern, is another reason why we should [have the ability to flag user profiles as well as content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101538/137484).

Comment: They look burninated now...

Comment: interesting, how did you find these profiles? That's the tricky part..

Comment: @Jeff: I've noticed spam from the account "mobile marketing sms" so tried searching for the keywords "market" and "sms" in the user database. I then noticed that "website" and "free" are also good keywords to search for spam accounts.

Comment: Ohy BABY that felt good.  I burninated all edit2's that smelled funny (left a couple that had personal info in their profiles).  The SMS users I burninated gave me a funny tickly feeling in my pants when I did it.

Comment: @Won't: Feel free to have fun with "edit3" as well.

Comment: @WladimirPalant: Silence of the Flowers, angry birds and soft peckers.

Comment: Coupon makes for good hits: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/111799/

Comment: SEO is another good one: http://www.google.com/search?&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fusers+seo

Comment: @OffBySome: After that round of deletions, I bet there are a **lot** of SEOre asses out there...

Comment: @Won't: And since I care about your fun - there you have some more great user profiles. Maybe StackExchange should simply build a competing service to Yellow Pages. There is already enough content, it only needs to be categorized.

Comment: I sure wish we could flag these accounts for moderation attention. With no posts/questions, we can't flag the posts.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### The trick is *finding* these spam profile user accounts, really.

For reference here are the two accounts, now burninated, in picture form:

[image]
[image]

If anyone has protips on what to search for to find accounts like these, I'm all ears.

Note that

1. Links in your "about me" field don't work for low-rep users; we don't allow more than 2 links by new users in this field, and they aren't actually *hyperlinked* until you have 15 rep.
2. The "website" field is not hyperlinked until you generate 15 rep.

... so the damage potential here is small.

That said of course we hate spammers and I love killing their user accounts, but **there is a weird little edge condition of users who set up accounts with spam profile info but never ask or answer questions**.

It's much harder for us to detect, so.. any tips, techniques, or ideas are welcome.

Comment: I edited my question to include the approach I used. But I think that the effort required isn't justified for a minor issue like this.

Comment: I think that profile that was created but has no activity whatsoever for X days (one week?) should raise a flag, if it contains "website" link and About Me information. Let members review such profiles with the ability to send moderator flag same way we can already [review bad posts](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day) for example.

Comment: Get an Akismet key, shoot them a little money and start running profiles through it in the background. After that, let "Community ♦ " raise a flag if a user's profile scores a hit in the future. Our SPAM could help Akismet get better, and I know of no better way to find these than to run the whole lot through an algorithm.

Comment: @Jeff - this is the exact reason I suggested adding the ability to flag user profiles: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101538/add-ability-to-flag-a-user-or-suggested-edit

Comment: Maybe a new mod tools tab for new, suspect accounts? Could be unregistered users with a website, registered users with low activity, but an "about me" field or a website, and anyone who has a spam flag on their content deemed valid.

Comment: Also don't forget that there's a minimum of 2000 rep. before `nofollow` is removed from even the Website field, let alone the About Me field.

Comment: What about feeding the current found spam user details and normal user details into a Bayesian filtering, I think Joel was written software that uses them in the past.

Comment: I just noticed [this user](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6419/apply-direct-jobs?tab=accounts) with 59 stack exchange accounts but not one post as yet

Comment: @martin we'll deal with that, sorry -- don't hesitate to email us if you find these, and we'll fix ASAP

Comment: @JeffAtwood: I've proposed a solution [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144869/hide-website-field-in-profiles-of-users-with-less-than-15-rep-from-users-not-log).

Comment: but Sir Jeff, my little concern here is - don't you think you might be helping these two spammers? by using their pic profile - because there are 636 views-(at time of me posting this)- which automatically qualifies to 636 hits.. that's more of a good job done thou..lol.. that's just my lil tots or concern

Comment: A Spam filter can be trained with supervised methods (given all the data SE must have), for example the [Naive Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering) algorithm has been successfully implemented in the past as Spam filters. It should apply here, as non-spam users have certain words and things on their profiles spam users don't and the algorithm learns about that. There are other more complex algorithms of course, but this one is easy to implement and straightforward if you are looking for a "quick" test to see if it is worth putting more time to it.

Comment: If any moderator stumbles upon this post, there's [now a way to detect users with spam in their profile on creation](https://github.com/SOBotics/UserStalker). You can jump into [Mobotics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59667/mobotics) and add your site to the list.

Comment: @BhargavRao is that bot still maintained, I think there are some other things you could add to the detection list.

Comment: concerning detecting accounts that don't post, see my post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421453/11107541. TL;DR these accounts are often huge pools that do things like put the same value in their website URL field.

Answer (score 19):

It still appears in [Google results](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=%22These+days+its+quite+easy+to+set+up+a+website+and+start+selling+products+online%22+stack+overflow&pbx=1&oq=%22These+days+its+quite+easy+to+set+up+a+website+and+start+selling+products+online%22+stack+overflow&aq=f&aqi=q-w1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=6704l8727l1l8898l15l13l0l0l0l0l403l2891l0.1.3.5.1l10l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=4b347bb79e2f4e74&biw=1400&bih=941) so in my opinion it's not good situation: Stack Overflow is indirectly linked with Spam.

Inactive accounts should be deleted [after six months of inactivity](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/), but it's too long for spam accounts.. IMO such accounts need to be zapped by moderator on spot.

Comment: They normally are. The problem is [if users decide to put flag-weight over good use of the flagging system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92015/are-people-abusing-spam-flagging-as-a-cheap-way-to-gain-flag-weight). If a user is `Moderator Attention` flagged for spam, his account will be squeezed into a tiny box (which itself will be thrown into the sea, where it will be eaten by a bigger fish), but if that does not happen, the account can live on by chance.

Comment: Thanks, guess we'll just have to report such spammers who live by chance in here and moderators will come over and eat their account. :)

Comment: I don't think that inactive accounts are deleted - see http://stackoverflow.com/users/356122/website-development-new-delhi for example.

Comment: @Wladimir thanks, looks like it's a bug then, according to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/when-will-inactive-accounts-be-deleted) and [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/) - probably the deleted posts are taken into account as activity.

Comment: Yes, [Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com/users+"free+shipping") are still ugly. And some of these are very old so the automatic deletion definitely doesn't work.

Comment: A decade later, inactive accounts still aren't deleted.  This one has a hundred accounts with zero activity, some 11 months old.  https://stackexchange.com/users/27319689/freedom-garage-door-services?tab=accounts  @jeffatwood

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune yeah this is one thing Stack Exchange does not want to address, for reasons I can't know. Anyway Jeff did not get your ping, and even if he did, nothing he can do, he isn't working at SE for long years and has no effect on it.