# Hide website field in profiles of users with less than 15 rep from users not logged in to control spam

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, hyperlinks, spam-detection

Here's an idea on how to combat [spam URLs in user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105218/is-spam-in-the-about-me-field-a-reason-to-worry): Hiding the website field in profiles of users with less than 15 rep<sup>1</sup> from users who are not logged in would disable this exploit by making the URL invisible to search engines (URLs in such profiles would remain visible to logged-in users).  I know this can inconvenience legitimate new users, but it would be a good idea to consider implementing this measure.

---

<sup>1</sup>*Currently, URLs in profiles of users with less than 15 reputation are not active links but are visible to everyone.*

Comment: Do search engines still follow URLs if they're plain text? If not, why do we care?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a peculiar request, because [as I already answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105228), none of the links on very new user profile pages are actually hyperlinked.

> Note that
>
> 1. Links in your **"about me" field** don't work for low-rep users; we don't allow more than 2 links by new users in this field, and they aren't actually hyperlinked until you have 15 rep.
> 2. The **"website" field** is not hyperlinked until you generate 15 rep.

I'm not clear how just displaying a *non-clickable* link could possibly be a problem. In other words:

> Website: example.com

Versus

> Website: [example.com](http://example.com)

Links that *are not links* are not "visible" to search engines already.

Comment: Okay, so this isn't really an issue. Can you edit the question to add the [status-declined] tag?