# URL and markdown link shown as regular text (not links) if I save and copy profile to all SE accounts from SO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I edited my website and description (which contains a markdown link) in SO and did a "Save and Copy Profile to All Stack Exchange Accounts", but in other accounts (I tried meta stack overflow and programmers), the links are shown as regular texts and not as links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have enough reputation yet here or on Programmers for the links to be rendered as links.

Jeff Atwood said you need [15 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144869/hide-website-field-in-profiles-of-users-with-less-than-15-rep-from-users-not-log) for your website link and the links in your description field to be rendered as actual links.

But apparently the [Remove new user restrictions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) rep level, which is just 10 rep, is enough.

Comment: It says new users cannot "post more than two hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile", but it does not say that the hyperlinks should be presented as regular texts instead of hyperlinks, hence I feel it's a bug.

Comment: I know, still looking for where that's stated.

Comment: @ruben2020: found the official reference, it's actually 15 rep you need and not 10.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. My rep increase to 11 on Programmers, and now the links are shown as links. But this means that the FAQ should be updated to reflect this.

Comment: Humm... interesting. Can't find anything about if/when that was changed or if it was 10 from the start.

Comment: And I also got a Teacher badge. Maybe that was it?

Comment: No, it's rep. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/81762/g-rocket has 14 rep, no teacher badge, and website is a link.