# How can I report Spam sent via my Stack Exchange profile contact info?

Tags: support, profile-page, spam

I received spam via my website contact form from somebody who specified that he got my contact via one of the Stack Exchange's sites.

I understand that Stack Exchange may not have to deal this kind of spam, but they may be able to track down the Stack Exchange profile of the spammer.

Who should I contact to report this issue?

To clarify:

- It's not a matter of private info being used (my website contact form isn't private), and I'm not complaining about somebody contacting me via my website (anyone can do that–they're are free to do it).
- I just think that if somebody is using Stack Exchange to spam, instead of as intended (helping the community), Stack Exchange should know about it. Just like they do when somebody spams on a forum.

**NOTE**

> The [Terms of Service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa) have been updated on April 19th 2016 to stop
>   the spammers.

Comment: "They may be able to track down the profile of the person who did it". How?

Comment: If I give them the info that was sent in the spam like the name, the email...

Comment: See my name here? I can send you an email from example@gmail.com and sign myself "Joe Shmoe". How will SE know it's me?

Comment: Yes the info I have could lead to noting that why I wrote "may be able". Also it's not a gmail email but an email associated with a software website which comes back ≈180 times on superuser

Comment: That should be in the question.

Comment: Sorry for this, I've edited the question

Comment: [security experts warn that stuff you put on the internet is on the internet](http://newsthump.com/2010/07/29/security-experts-warn-that-stuff-you-put-on-the-internet-is-on-the-internet/)

Comment: @EnergyNumbers It's not a matter of private info (my website contact form isn't private) .  I don't even complain about somebody contacting me via my website (anyone can do that) but I just think that if somebody if using SE to spam instead of using SE as it is intended (helping the community), SE should know about it.

Comment: Put every piece of relevant info you know in the question.

Comment: Google it: there is a way to get the IP address (if I remember correctly) from an email.

Comment: @DaniSpringer See the edit in the question. I can't give the IP because the spam when through my website server first before arriving in my gmail account and (apparently) there is no way O can get the ip with them.

Comment: Again, put all of that in the question! Good luck!

Comment: @Arone: It's not listed in the headers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is spam in the "about me" field a reason to worry?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105218/is-spam-in-the-about-me-field-a-reason-to-worry)

Comment: @gnat: I don't see how this is a question of that at all.

Answer (score 15):

Nothing to report.

If you don't want to be spammed, don't publish your contact info. Period.

I don't see any reason for SE team to spend their time on such things.

Comment: It's not a matter of private info (my website contact form isn't private) . I don't even complain about somebody contacting me via my website (anyone can do that) but I just think that if somebody if using SE to spam instead of using SE as it is intended (helping the community), SE should know about it. Just like they do when somebody if spamming on the forums

Comment: The OP wasn't asking for opinions, rather what to do.

Comment: @ArthurFischer just what they do with others profile who spam.

Comment: @Dani I know, and the first sentence means "nothing to do", which is direct response to what the OP asked.

Comment: I'd change it. But that's my opinion ;)

Comment: @Dani so post a new answer. :)

Answer (score 6):

To add to Shadow's excellent and on-the-nose answer, no, there is nothing anyone can do.

Email links don't create an audit trail, "From" fields are forgeable (calling that "forging" is a reach, frankly), and you have no legal right to the personal information of other SE users. In reality, it's more likely your address was harvested by robots/crawlers, not an actual SE user.

Spam via email is a fact of life. Either publish your email address and deal with it (using a combination of automated and brain-powered filtering), or do not publish your email address.

I was going to send you an email pretending to be Jon Skeet to prove the point, but apparently you've already removed your address from your profile so, problem solved. :)

Comment: It's not a matter of private info being used (my website contact form isn't private!). I don't even complain about somebody contacting me via my website (anyone can do that there are free to do it!).  I just think that if somebody if using SE to spam instead of using SE as it is intended (helping the community), SE should know about it. Just like they do when somebody if spamming on the forums

Comment: @Arone: You do not need to write a paragraph in the question and then copy it verbatim onto all the answers. I read it the first time! And I understand what you're saying, and appreciate your laudable goals, but this is (a) technically infeasible, (b) probably not what you think it is, and (c) not a worthwhile use of engineer time, especially when those engineers have enough to do countering [spam actually written _on_ the network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269478/155739), to want to spend time countering spam sent _off_ it. Just turn on your spam filter and move on. Life's too short!

Comment: Hang on, you got spam from your contact form, saying that they got your contact from SE? Surely they didn't need to, because they used your contact form....

Comment: Sorry for the copypast but  I thought you didn't read it because you answer focused on the private info used, not on the fact that there is people using SE to spam (on the forum they are targeted so why not if they used the website in another way). For your second comment : Because Ana mentioned she has seen my profile on SuperUser. I wasn't contacted via this profile but via another profile where the website is still there.

Comment: Ok well you're not listening, so...

Comment: Spammers often lie. "I got your contact info from SE" is as likely to be true as "I have access to the estate of someone with the same last name as you." There's no reason for SE to get involved because they don't have a mechanism that the spammers could be misusing.