# Disable Twitter/GitHub links for low-rep users

Tags: feature-request, reputation, profile-page, new-users, spam

Currently, hyperlinks in "About me" and "Website link" in our user profile pages are disabled for low-rep users in order to prevent from malicious links. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105228/341401) for details.

Hyperlinks for Twitter and GitHub in profile are, however, enabled even for low-rep users. In SOja, I found a possibly-spam user who links to a spammy account on Twitter. So how about disabling these links for low-rep users?

To be clear: this proposal is to make it so that the user can still add the link, but you can't click on it to go to the new page.

Comment: I vote YES: Disable those links until they generate 15 reputation.