# What determines the outcome of a spam/offensive flag?

Tags: support, flags, spam, offensive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I'm not gaining flag weight for my Spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109100/im-not-gaining-flag-weight-for-my-spam-flags)

Gaming was hit with some spam today. I flagged it all as such, and it was deleted. This is my most recent flagging history:

> [image: Flagging Summary screenshot]

Two things I noticed:

1. Those flags now have a "helpful" (and, possibly, "declined") outcome, and affect flag weight. At least I *think* that's a semi-recent development, because none of my other spam/offensive flags have that, despite the flagged posts being deleted.
2. All those posts were deleted (as indicated by the reddish background), but the last flag doesn't have an outcome, for some reason.

At least the first and last flags in that picture were both answered by a ♦ moderator (because their post score isn't low enough for a community destruction), but only the first one has an outcome.

So, what happened here?

Comment: Oddly spam flags get "Helpful" as the response sometimes, where as other flags get "helpful" (lower/uppercase h/H) for no apparent reason.

Comment: Was that really the same user? If yes, [please do not use the spam flags, but flag for moderator attention instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92015/are-people-abusing-spam-flagging-as-a-cheap-way-to-gain-flag-weight).

Comment: @PaddedCell I don't see why. I thought flagging all the spam was what you were supposed to do, to help out the moderators. In any case, this was *blatant* spam, not just promoting something the user is affiliated with. As in, anonymous user, gibberish, and a link to some unrelated article with ads. I didn't pay close attention to the usernames, but it was at least 2 people (although they ended up merged into the Spaminator).

Comment: There may be a difference based on whether the mod manually accepted the flag, or the flag was automagically accepted by the system based on some action the moderator took. Our team has been tweaking the flag system a lot in recent weeks, so I'm not sure of the details.

Comment: Welp, [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109100/im-not-gaining-flag-weight-for-my-spam-flags) got the answer I was looking for. Oh well, flagging as dupe...