# Limit spam flags towards the same user

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam

> ***Originated from here:** [Are people abusing spam flagging as a cheap way to gain flag weight?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92015/are-people-abusing-spam-flagging-as-a-cheap-way-to-gain-flag-weight)*
>
> ***Related:** [Gaming the system with spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49159/gaming-the-system-with-spam-flags)*

As shown in the past, sometimes Spam-Flags are just not used the right way. Those `Spam-Flag Spammers` should have the ability to do that.

Some solutions I can think of:

- Limit spam flagging of the same user (from the same user) to *x* flags.
- If a user flags another user more then *x* times for spam, turn those spam-flags into one `Moderator Attention` flag and deny further spam flags.

This would prevent an extremely high spam-flag count and people gaming the flag-wight system.

Answer (score 5):

Speaking as someone who flags fairly regularly I was under the impression this was the correct behaviour. For example I flagged a lot of posts by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/945100/user945100) under the belief that flagging *all* of the posts would feed into automated spam detection and/or allow patterns of spammyness to be spotted by the system without demanding time from moderators, and even if it came down to manual intervention made it clear that it wasn't just a one-off incident of unacknowledged selfpromotion, but the raison d'être for the creation of the account.

What might be useful though would be being able to specifically [flag an account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users) instead of just a post, but that's status-declined.

Comment: I used to do that but it seems like the consensus is that if there are more than 2-3 posts, it's better to do one mod flag describing the issue. And that's the indirect way to flag an account as well in that if every post contains spam I'll suggest in the message in the mod flag that the whole account gets deleted.