# Searching posts I've flagged

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam, search

When looking through [new answers to old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) it's not uncommon to come across spam that is substantially similar to things I know I've already flagged. For "bulk" spam, consisting of more than about 3 posts I'm already using a [custom flag reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107313/153020) to indicate the user(s) and url(s) involved. I'd like to be able to link to older, now deleted spam that I've spotted in the past in the flags too, to make the scale of the spam more obvious to moderators handling them. I can see these still *if* I can find the post, but there's no easy way of finding them.

Making it easier to find posts which I have previously flagged has two benefits that I can see:

1. Blacklisting persistently spammed URLs
2. Adding evidence to support flags on posts which at first glance seem innocuous

Currently the options for this are:

1. Write a hand wavey statement about having seen this same spam in the past
2. Manually search through my flag history

Manual searching is very tedious. Instead I'd propose a new search operator, perhaps `is:flagged` which could be used to search only posts from my flag history.

There doesn't seem to be much risk here - it's only helping users find things they could already find anyway.

Comment: The moderator tools does have the ability to detect duplicate posts. If a user is copy/pasting their spam, it will show up in the flag dashboard.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - the kinds of posts I was thinking of are the ones which aren't identical, certainly not enough to trip any of the duplicate post flags I've seen in the 10k flag queue.

Answer (score 7):

Sometime in the last couple years, the flags page gained filters, like this:

[image: flag filters]

Click on the "spam flags" link (or, if you prefer, the "helpful" link under it) to see only your spam flags on the page.  It's still not searchable and pagination still kicks in after 50 entries, but I've found this really helpful for finding *that post I know I flagged, but it's buried by other flags*.